# Match content of a report where column names dynamic using java

Tags: java

I have a dynamic report to generate where column names are fetch from database table which displays the rooms booked by a employee on a given period. Its like below,

```
Name Dept Room1(2) Room2(2) Room3(3) Total

A    D1     1        1                 2 
B    D2     2                 1        3
B    D3     1        1        1        3
```

Rooms can be dynamic where it can have Room4 or Room5 if there is any booking for the identified period.

I made a `RoomHeaderDTO` list which has the names ordered by the capacity of the room (in brackets of the room name it display the capacity). Name and Dept column i made hard coded and i populate the room names by iterating the list.

Now my problem is how to place the values on number of booking in relevant room. i have another list of DTO which names `ContentDTO` which have each rows values populate with. For example,

```
ContentDTO 
  String name;  //A
  String dept;  //D1
  String roomName; //Room1(2)
  int noOfBooking; //1
```

So another instance of DTO contains values A, D1, Room2(2), 1 like wise.

So above is how the DTO looks like for first row. (I have commented the values it will initialized)

Since the column name is dynamic, How should i identify the relevant room name and put the num of booking value when i iterate the `ContentDTO` (rows) list

Comment: Are the dynamic room numbers always "Room1", "Room2", etc, in order? It might help to see some of the code you are using the populate the DTO.

Comment: yes its already order by